# Docker Parameterize Files Passed Inside

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to pass a directory inside the container, eventually where this can be automated. However I don't see any alternative other than physically editing the Dockerfile and manually typing the specific directory to be added.

Note: I have tried mounted volumes, however that solution doesn't help my issue, as I want to eventually call the container on a directory which will eventually have a script run on the directory in the container--not simply copying the local directory inside the container.

Method 1:

```
$ --build-arg project_directory=/path/to/dir

ARG project_directory
ADD $project_directory .
```

My unsuccessful solution assumes that I can use the argument's value as a basic string that the `ADD` command can interpret just as if I was just manually entering the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not simply copying the local directory inside the container

That's exactly what you're doing now, by using `ADD $project_directory`. If you need to make changes from the container and have them reflected onto the host, use:

```
docker run -v $host_dir:$container_dir image:tag
```

The command above launches a new container, and it's quite possible for you to launch it with different directory names. You can do so in a loop, from a jenkins pipeline, a shell script, or whatever suits your development environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
container_dir=/workspace
for directory in /src /realsrc /kickasssrc
do
    docker run -v $directory:$container_dir image:tag
done
```

Comment: running `docker run -it -v path/to/dir/to/add:path/in/container {image}` renders me with an `[Ernno 2] No such file or directory`. Am I understanding your response where by adding that with the `-v` flag, I do not have to add anything else in the docker file? It simply adds the host directory to the specified path in the container?

Comment: Sounds like you may need to `mkdir -p` the target path in your Dockerfile

Comment: There's no need to change the Dockerfile, path `/` exists, and you should be able to mount `/your/src/dir` onto `/workspace`.